# Unterminated String Constant in Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-xi

I'm creating a form in ASP.NET that would generate a report. And I'm using Crystal Report XI for the report.

I use a multi line text box in the form as one of the input media. I then tried to input a single line value in the text box. It's successfully saved in the database, also displayed as it's supposed to be in the CrystalReportViewer. I also could export and print the report.

The problem occurs when I tried to input a multi line value in the text box. It's also saved and displayed successfully, the only problem is when I tried to export and print the report. The pop-up window didn't pop out and I got the `Unterminated String Constant` error message as return.

Does Crystal Report have a multiline issue, or is it the ASP.NET?

Comment: Have you read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324776/crystal-reports-passing-multiline-parameter-values

Comment: I've tried the solution given in the post, but still didn't solve the Unterminated String Constant issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on this for days, and assuming that the problem lies on the Crystal Report exporting process. The Crystal Report couldn't export the report if the Crystal Report Viewer is in the same page with a form that contain a textarea with multiline value in it.

I've tried to use a lot of Newline replacement methods including the SQL Replace function but none of them could solve the problem.

Finally I decided to show the report and put the Crystal Report Viewer in a separated page, and things are now going back to work.